# Writing the content of StringBuilder to a file without calling ToString()

Tags: c#

Let's imagine that I have a `StringBuilder` and I cannot refactor it to use a stream. I want to write the content of my `StrinBuilder` to a file but I don't want to make an extra copy of the content in memory i.e I don't want to call `ToString()`.

Can I get the content without making an extra copy in memory ?

*I believe that prior to version 2 ToString() could avoid copying by using copy on write, but this no longer is the case.*

Comment: If you're writing the contents of a `StringBuilder` to a file...isn't that by definition making a copy?

Comment: @RichardEverett Yes, it is making a copy. I meant a copy in memory, I shall clarify the question.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, it's not about making a copy per se, it's about making a copy of the whole thing at once. In other words, if you have a multi-megabyte `StringBuilder`, avoid requiring a multi-megabyte allocation just to store that to disk.

If that is correct, you can use [`StringBuilder.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx) with a smaller fixed-size buffer to copy the data out in blocks. You can then write those smaller blocks directly to any stream you like.

Answer (score 5):

Writing 1 byte at a time can be very slow for large strings, so implementing hvd's suggestion of StringBuilder.CopyTo(..):

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FilePath))
 {
     const int bufferSize = 10000;
     char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];

     for (int i = 0; i < builder.Length; i += bufferSize)
     {
         int count = Math.Min(bufferSize, builder.Length - i);
         builder.CopyTo(i, buffer, 0, count);
         sw.Write(buffer, 0, count);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

you can avoid the `ToString()` by accessing the `char` elements of the `StringBuilder` by index

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// fill StringBuilder 
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\file.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(sb[i]);
    }
}
```